Problema com tween no Godot 4
Estou com um problema em um tween que está sendo chamado por um signal dentro do node de CharacterBody2D no Godot 4, basicamente a animação do tween não acontece, já debuguei vendo se a função é chamada dentro da conexão do signal no _ready, os valores são atribuídos corretamente, e, tudo acontece normalmente, só o tween que não executa a animação.
Abaixo está o CharacterBody2D conectando ao signal de HurtboxComponent

extends CharacterBody2D

@onready var hurt_component: HurtComponent = $HurtComponent
var knockback_vector: Vector2 = Vector2(-200, 200)

func _ready():
    hurt_component.take_damage.connect(knockback)

func knockback(duration = 0.25):
    var knockback_tween = get_tree().create_tween()
    knockback_tween.tween_property(self, "knockback_vector", Vector2.ZERO, duration)

E aqui o HurtboxComponent emitindo o sinal assim que a colisão acontece e o player perde vida

class_name HurtComponent
extends Node

@export var hurtbox_component: HurtboxComponent
@export var stats_component: StatsComponent
@export var invencible: Timer

func _ready():
    invencible.timeout.connect(func():
        hurtbox_component.is_invencible = false
    )
    hurtbox_component.hurt.connect(func(hitbox_component: HitboxComponent):
        hurtbox_component.is_invencible = true
        stats_component.health -= hitbox_component.damage
        
        take_damage.emit()
        invencible.start()
    )

signal take_damage(Vector2)

Testes realizados:

A função knockback é executada no _ready dentro do signal take_damage
O tween é criado corretamente
HurtComponent recebe a função de callback knockback

